# taggable_friends are deperated from april 4 2018

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-friends

The api was working fine till last week but now its responding with an empty array. when i visit the FB official graph api document i.e. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/taggable_friends/

It says that it has been deprecated from 4th April. Please if you guys know any alternate to find user's friend list and their pictures.

Thanks

Comment: Sad, but true. This makes Facebook pretty much irrelevant to count on as the login platform for any social app you're building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no alternative, take a look at the breaking changes: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes/

There is no way to get access to any user/friend data anymore, if the user did not authorize your App first.